# The "expected_title" procedure throws wrong error on expected title

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have some issues with "expected_title" procedure from watir-page-helper.
It is throwing an error like the current web page has a different title than the expected one, although it is the correct title:

```
RuntimeError: Expected title 'Some title' instead of 'Some Title'.
```

This happens randomly, and my tests fail frequently on different pages. The website on which I am working is loading in a reasonable amount of time, I don't think it is a loading page issue.

To initialize the pages I am using the next method:

```
@new_mail_editor = Module::Page.new(@browser, false)
```

This is for pages that are opened when accessing links.

Does someone have a clue why this is happening?
Is there a way to dodge this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watir-page-helper has been [end-of-lifed](http://watirmelon.com/2012/03/29/watir-page-helper-has-been-end-of-lifed/), you should try [page-object](https://rubygems.org/gems/page-object) gem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Željko. I hope is not to complicated changing watir-page-helper with page-object in my project.

Comment: Alister Scott wrote a blog post on converting to PO at http://watirmelon.com/2012/03/29/watir-page-helper-has-been-end-of-lifed/

Answer (score 0):

Meantime I found out what I was doing wrong. When initializing the browser and checking the title, I was using "has_expected_title?" instead of "expected_title". It seems that I didn't used correctly the first function
Now everything works great.